# How to catch custom eventEmitter event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

Let's say in my controller I'm emitting an event:

`@Output() somethingUpdated = new EventEmitter();`

and in method:

```
***
this.somethingUpdated.emit();
***
```

in view i added:

`(somethingUpdated)="somethingUpdated($event)"`

In directive I have:

```
  @HostListener('somethingUpdated', ['$event'])
  somethingUpdated() {
    console.log('somethingUpdated');
  }
```

But this doesn't work.

What an I doing wrong?

Comment: Things like `somethingUpdated` are not events on the document that you can watch using `@HostListener`.

Comment: Event emitted from `EventEmitter` doesn't bubble

Comment: @torazaburo how to be then?

Comment: You can either use `element.dispatchEvent()` to fire a DOM event that bubbles, or use a shared service

Comment: When do you want the event to fire?

Comment: @torazaburo after ngbDropdown was opened

Comment: ngbDropdown exposes an output called `openChange`. Bind to that by specifying `(openChange)="dropdownOpened($event)"` when you invoke it. Then in `dropdownOpened`, emit onto your `somethingUpdated` output.

Comment: @torazaburo i know that
it's already done, but how to catch this event in custom directive? (something like global events)

Comment: @torazaburo like how to edit directive code to catch my event, what i need  to catch this event in directive?

Comment: @torazaburo sure, ngbDropdown has such method! but in this dropdown (inner element) i have `dropdown-menu` with `custom directive`, how on this inner element i can listen outer event?

Answer (score 0):

You're binding that handler to an event on the document. But that's not what you want, you want the handler receiving events from the output source you defined.

(The output source is the thing emitting the event btw).

Any example of using Outputs in Angular (2+) will point you in the right direction.

Here's the docs, check it out, you'll see.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Specifically, look for the section, "Parent listens for child event"

The format you use there (binding to a doc event) would be useful if say, you wanted a handler to fire every time the document was resized.

Comment: i need an example with directive
with components - all is clear

Comment: Hmm...a directive is just a component without a template (conversely, you can think of components as "directives with a template" though that's not as useful). I would assume it would be the same story. The example in the docs should give you what you need.